Cannot perform inference on SageMaker Real Time Endpoint when passing in array
I'm having trouble with performing inference on a SageMaker Real-Time endpoint. The model can be successfully deployed, but I cannot seem to get a response. I am using StableBaselines 3 MaskablePPO model. I have packaged the directory correctly and can deploy the endpoint.
import os
import sb3_contrib
from sb3_contrib import MaskablePPO

def model_fn(model_dir):
    """
    Load the model for inference
    """

    model_path = os.path.join(model_dir, "final_model.zip")

    model = MaskablePPO.load(model_path)

    return model

def predict_fn(input_data, model):
    """
    Apply model to the incoming request
    """

    try:
        observation = body['observation']
        
        action, _ = model.predict(observation, action_masks=None, deterministic=True)
    
        output = json.dumps(action)

        return output
    except:
        return {"error": "Terrible"}

def input_fn(request_body, request_content_type):
    """
    Deserialize and prepare the prediction input
    """

    if request_content_type == "application/json":
        request = json.loads(request_body)
    else:
        request = request_body

    return request

def output_fn(prediction, response_content_type):
    """
    Serialize and prepare the prediction output
    """

    if response_content_type == "application/json":
        response = str(prediction)
    else:
        response = str(prediction)

    return response

The code I'm using to invoke the endpoint is here:
model = PyTorchModel(
    entry_point="inference.py",
    model_data="<redacted bucket name>",
    role=get_execution_role(),
    framework_version="1.5",
    py_version="py3",
)

predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge", endpoint_name=endpoint_name
)

request = {
   "observation": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

predictor.predict(json.dumps(request))

It keeps returning this error:
"ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from primary and could not load the entire response body."
I cannot get much useful information out of this error and the CloudWatch logs do not offer much insight either. Not sure what the issue is.
Any help is appreciated!

Can you try changing how you passed your data, request object, to not use json.dumps, and pass it directly. And then changing during your .deploy call to use serializer=JSONSerializer(), deserializer=JSONDeserializer(). These are coming from from sagemaker.serializers import JSONSerializer and from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer

@FranciscoParrilla I made the recommended changes and still got the same error. I'm wondering whether the issue is in my inference.py script. I tested the functions locally and got the expected functionality, so the issue must be on the sagemaker side. I also enabled data capture and set SAGEMAKER_CONTAINER_LOG_LEVEL to 10 to debug the issue. Unfortunately, the data capture logs are not showing up in S3 and the CloudWatch Logs are still only showing [INFO] logs.

are there any logs to verify your model is loaded correctly? I see you are using from sb3_contrib import MaskablePPO and the file is final_model.zip. Can you share the training code you used? For code for the training job definition and entrypoint.

Sort of. I have logs saying that the model loaded and that the model server started. Then I have a series of successful connection attempts to "/home/model-server/tmp/.mms.sock.9000". However, I then get a log saying "[INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - Backend worker process died." This is followed by "[WARN ] W-9000-model com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.BatchAggregator - Load model failed: model, error: Worker died." and "[INFO ] W-9000-model-stdout com.amazonaws.ml.mms.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle - AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'".

@FranciscoParrilla A little more context: If I let the PyTorchModel constructor make a default container (as I do in the code) instead of specifying one in the image_uri parameter, then I get the model unresponsive error and an attribute error about cloudpickle not being able to load a make_function. If I specify the image_uri, then I get a model timeout error and the model doesn't load properly, generating the logs described above. In my requirements.txt file, I have pickle5. Maybe I should change it to cloudpickle==2.2.1 as I have seen people recommend online.
